# Unable to debug Go in visual studio code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I have a folder, D:\Data\Git\go\src\demo containing one file, main.go.
I have installed go1.12.6 windows/amd64. (I am running Windows 10)
I am unable to debug the application - the debugger flashes on the screen then disappears ==> nothing happens ==>  even though I have set a breakpoint, it does not break into the code for interactive step-through!
I can run the app from the commandline ==> go run main.go (current directory is where main.go is located)

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my app:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    s = s[1:4]
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

How do I get to debug in VS Code?

Comment: You have a strange definition of "nothing happens." It sounds like your program is successfully executing to completion.

Comment: I set a breakpoint.  VS Code is not catching the breakpoint and entering debug step-through.  Also, nothing is printed to the console.

Comment: Ctrl + shift + p, cmd box opens, type in go: install/update tools, install them all, then run debug again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

Ctrl+Shift+P ==> Open Launch.json ==> Save ==> Voila!

(It works.  I am now able to step through and debug a simple application with one main.go file in Visual Studio Code)

Note that I have installed all of the dev tools (as per @owlwalks above), as well as dlv (see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code)